# For any sentence $\phi$ of first-order logic, the only sentence which is an initial segment of $\phi$ is $\phi$ itself.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Given two expressions $\phi$ and $\psi$, call $\psi$ an initial segment of $\phi$ if and only if $\phi$ can be obtained by concatenating some (possibly no) symbols to the right-hand end of $\psi$. For example, $\neg$ is an initial segment of $\neg \neg A$.

Now I am a good way through a proof that or any sentence $\phi$ of  first-order logic, the only sentence which is an initial segment of $\phi$ is $\phi$ itself.  I am proving it by strong induction on the length of sentences, by considering the different possible forms $\phi$ may take, and **I have managed all the cases except when $\phi$ is $\forall v \psi$ for some $v$ and $\psi$**.

Here's where I've got to on this last part.

Let $\chi$ be an initial segment of $\phi$. Then $\chi$ must be of the form $\forall v' \psi'$ for some $v'$ and some $\psi'$. Now we want to show that $\chi$ must be $\phi$ by showing that $v'$ and $\psi'$ must be $v$ and $\psi$, respectively. But the issue is a bit complicated because  $\psi$ and $\psi'$ could be formulas with open variables, and in that case they won't possess the inductive property (which is precisely the property I am trying to prove $\phi$ has). What's more, I don't know what to say about $v$. I haven't proved have an analogous theorem for terms, but my feeling is that we don't need to (when I watched my tutor prove this he didn't make use of any such theorem). How might I navigate this tricky business at the end of my proof?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming your syntax requires parentheses (eg, we need $(P \land Q)$ instead of $P \land Q$). If you don’t require parentheses but instead have an order of operations, this isn’t true, as the example $P \land Q$ demonstrates (where $P$ is an initial segment).

The trick here is quite simple. All you have to do is drop the requirement that the proposition be a sentence. If you do this, then you are able to do this final inductive step, since we know that $\psi’$ would be an initial segment of $\psi$ and thus $\psi$ itself.

Comment: Yes it requires parentheses. And do you mean change the claim I am trying to prove? I don't want to do that at the moment

Comment: @DanÖz I don’t really understand what you’re saying. All you have to do is generalise what you’re trying to prove by replacing the word “sentence” with “proposition”, and everything works. Do you have some sort of emotional aversion to doing so?